# How to clear semaphores semadj?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, semaphore

How to set semaphores ***semadj*** value to 0 without setting semaphores value?
I know ***semctl*** with *SETVAL* can clear ***semadj*** but it sets sem. val.

Comment: The bigger question is, why are you doing semaphore stuff with SEM_UNDO and then trying to defeat the very thing it does?

Comment: Im solving producer-consumer problem :) one process is consumer and increments Orders semaphore, other process is producer and increments Deliveries semaphore. Consumer is loop: increment Orders, wait for Delivers. Producer is loop too: wait for Orders, increment Delivers. Producer "takes order" with SEM_UDO - in case it gets terminated b4 delivery. But I dont want producer to undo every delivery he ever took,  so i want to "revoke" undo of successfull deliveries. Hope you got it ;)

Comment: @cHao thanks to you i realized i will be also satisfied with answer to different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057454/how-to-revoke-sem-undo-of-latest-operation-on-semaphore