# How to revoke SEM_UNDO of latest operation on semaphore?

Tags: linux, ipc, semaphore

My problem: 
A,B - semaphores.

Process is loop:

1. waits for A >= 1, decrements A
2. does some computation
3. increments B.
4. back to 1.

Goal: After process terminates i need decrements of A be equal to increments of B.

So i figure out i will add flag SEM_UNDO in 1. but it undos every DEcrement ever made to A by that process. How to revoke / undo SEM_UNDO from 1. when process reaches 4.?

Comment: If `A` and `B` don't match up in the end, you have bigger problems than SEM_UNDO.  It seems like you're kinda misunderstanding the part that semaphores play in things.  How bout you show us some code, and we can help you figure out how to avoid these contortions.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i was enlightened when thinking about problem as "undoing" SEM_UNDO rather then "revoking" it.

after calling semop() with operation +x with SEM_UNDO, you can later undo that SEM_UNDO by calling  *semop()* again with two operations:

1. -x with SEM_UNDO
2. +x without SEM_UNDO

Comment: I confess I can't follow what the heck you are doing but my guess is that you have painted yourself into a corner and now think cutting a hole in wall to escape out through another room is a solution.

Comment: @Duck there was a mistake in part of question where i was decribing what i was trying to do - just corrected it. Sorry everyone.

Comment: This is not correct. The way to ensure your process does not have outstanding undos when it terminates is to do both the + and - operations *with* SEM_UNDO.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-4415/svipc-65382/: "When performing a semaphore operation with SEM_UNDO in effect, you must also have SEM_UNDO in effect for the call that performs the reversing operation. When the process runs normally, the reversing operation updates the undo structure with a complementary value. This ensures that, unless the process is aborted, the values applied to the undo structure are canceled to zero. When the undo structure reaches zero, it is removed."

Comment: @craig65535 right, i fixed it, please check. Thanks.

Comment: @Maq So you call the -x and +x every time you enter the step4 ? I am facing with the similar issue but it doesn't work.. for some reason adding the code even introduces a dead lock.